# Does fakemail support HTML emails?

Tags: testing, email-validation

I'm using the python version of fakemail for testing and it was easy to setup and works great for text/plain emails but it doesn't seem to work for HTML (multipart/mixed) emails.

Can someone confirm this? It's a noisy search and there doesn't seem to be anything on the SourceForge site or homepage of the project.

Also, if fakemail doesn't support HTML emails, what do you use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, fakemail does support HTML emails. Although I haven't determined the cause, on one system where the application was sending using PHPMailer I didn't receive the emails while on another similarly configured system I did.

Postfix's smtp-sink also was easy to setup for testing purposes. You don't need to run Postfix proper, just the smtp-sink utility, i.e.:

```
smtp-sink -u root -d %d.%H.%M.%S 192.168.1.10:25 10
```

But fakemail is preferred - at least in my case - since smtp-sink writes out the files with a timestamp.hex string whereas fakemail writes them out as foo@example.com.N where N is the occurrence of the same address.